# Use Twig object as tag

Tags: tags, twig, twig-extension

Is there any way to use any random object as a tag in Twig?

I know I can set a variable - it's just that this would really be cleaner.

i.e.

```
{{ get_an_entry() }}
    {{ name }} is {{ id }}
{{ end }}
```

or

```
{{ entry }}
    {{ name }} is {{ id }}
{{ end }}
```

In the examples, the name and id values would come from entry or the return of get_an_entry()

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It just need the `__toString()` PHP magic method implemented. An usage like that in fact triggers a string conversion.

Comment: I can use it inline yes like {{ entry.name }} - the question however is can I use it in a block context somehow. Like {{ entry }}{{ name }}{{ endentry }}

Comment: Non you can't, that's not Twig syntax.